# Why is "Run configurations" invisible in my perspective?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Namely, I am working on a "New project wizard" plugin. When new project is created I open my perspective to display the project there. It is displayed as expected, but I can not run it since I can not see "Run configurations" menu item under my "Run" menu. I've been looking for a way to get this menu item back with no success. Now, I got curious why is it invisible. Someone knows it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window > Customize Perspective`.

Look at the `Command Groups Availability` and select `Launch`.

You may also want `Launch` on `Tool Bar Visibility`.

Comment: Now I see I was a bit imprecise with my question. After applying your solution I can run the project from my perspective as well. But what I want to achieve is that those commands are automatically visible the moment the project is created and perspective opened. So the user is not required to do it manually the way you've just described.

Comment: Is this a perspective you are creating?

Comment: Yes, it is. 

The solution I was looking for was to add `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension. For extension to add `Launch Command Group` to the `Run` menu the extension's `targetID` should be `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet`.

Тhanks to @greg-449 answer I managed to find it on stackoverflow.com eventually :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335458/eclipse-plug-in-add-launch-command-group-to-custom-perspective